# Variable not being set in completion handler

Tags: swift, api

I'm making an api call in my function and trying to mutate the value of the  class variable temperatureF with the value from the API call.  The API is going through and I'm not getting any error messages, but the variable isn't being changed.  My code is below. The url of the API has been changed for security reasons.  I also tried dispatching the self.temperature line to the main queue but that didn't work either.

```
class weatherModel {

    var temperatureF : Float? = 1

    func readWeather(){

        let postEndpoint: String = "myurl.com"
        guard let weatherUrl = NSURL(string: postEndpoint) else {
            print ("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: weatherUrl)

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data: NSData?,  response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }

            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling GET on /posts/1")
                print(error)
                return
            }
            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            let post: NSDictionary
            do {
               post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                    options: []) as! NSDictionary
            } catch {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }

          self.temperatureF = post["current_observation"]!["temp_f"] as? Float


    }
    task.resume()    
}
}
```

Comment: Are you accessing the variable after the block has completed? Leeks like it will run async.

Comment: I think you have to use self.temperatureF.

Comment: BTW, you should not use the xcode tag as you are not asking a question about xcode. Thanks.

Comment: Will you display the response dictionary (post) ?

Comment: @JigarTarsariya No I won't be displaying it.  I will just be using it to get values.  There will be more variables than temperatureF

Comment: I suggest Add a breakpoint to check the content of post

Comment: @luiyezheng the post variable works fine because when I print what I want the variable to be set too it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now.  It was a problem with how I was accessing the variable. Thanks for all the suggestions.